Every real function is the sum of two bijections
Context. We are in $\mathsf{ZFC}$.
Problem. Given a function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ prove that there exist two bijective functions $g$ and $h$ from $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f = g + h$ (i.e. $\forall x \in \mathbb R \ f(x) = g(x) +h(x)$).
My attempt. My idea was, firstly, to well order $\mathbb R$ using $\mathsf{AC}$, so $(\mathbb R,<)$ is well-ordered, then I'd like to construct $g$ and $h$ by transfinite recursion in a way that they're bijections and their sum gives $f$ in each passage. Let's say (for convenience) that $|\mathbb R| = 2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_\varepsilon = |\omega_\varepsilon|$, and let $F : \omega_\varepsilon \to \mathbb R$ be a bijection. I start defining $f_0 = g_0 = \emptyset$, then, given:
$$\overline y :=\min\{y \in \mathbb R \setminus \text{Im}(g_\alpha) |\ g_{\alpha} \cup \{(F(\alpha),y)\} \ \text{is bijective}\}$$
I can define:
$$ g_{\alpha + 1} = \begin{cases}
g_{\alpha} \cup \{(F(\alpha),\overline y)\} &\text{if $\alpha \in \omega_\varepsilon$} \\
\emptyset &\text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}$$
and similarly:
$$ \overline y := \min\{y \in \mathbb R \setminus \text{Im}(h_\alpha) |\ h_{\alpha} \cup \{(F(\alpha),y)\} \ \text{is bijective and $h(F(\alpha))+g(F(\alpha)) = f(F(\alpha))$}\}$$
$$ h_{\alpha + 1} = \begin{cases}
h_{\alpha} \cup \{(F(\alpha),\overline y)\} &\text{if $\alpha \in \omega_\varepsilon$} \\
\emptyset &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and lastly, for limit cases, $g_\lambda = \bigcup_{\gamma < \lambda} g_\gamma$ and $h_\lambda = \bigcup_{\gamma < \lambda} h_\gamma$. Now I just define:
$$g:= \bigcup_{\alpha < \omega_\varepsilon} g_\alpha \quad \text{and} \quad h:= \bigcup_{\alpha < \omega_\varepsilon} h_\alpha $$
I think it is trivial that $g$ and $h$ are bijective functions (since they're union of compatible bijective functions). Now the last two things to do are:

prove that the definitions above are well-defined (i.e. prove the minimums exist, that is the sets are not empty).
prove that $f = h + g$.

About 1 I think that $\{y \in \mathbb R \setminus \text{Im}(g_\alpha) |\ g_{\alpha} \cup \{(F(\alpha),y)\} \ \text{is bijective}\} \ne \emptyset$ it's quiet obvious, due to the fact that $|\text{Im}(g_\alpha)| = |\alpha| < |\omega_\varepsilon| = |\mathbb R| \implies \text{Im}(g_\alpha) \subsetneq \mathbb R \implies \mathbb R \setminus \text{Im}(g_\alpha) \ne \emptyset$, so anything in there works to exend $g_\alpha$ keeping the bijectivity (or at least I think so). We can argue similarly for $h_\alpha$ to get $\mathbb R \setminus \text{Im}(h_\alpha) \ne \emptyset$, the problem is now to choose something in there that respects the sum. The obvious choice would be $f(F(\alpha)) - g_{\alpha + 1}(F(\alpha))$, but how do I know that such an element actually belongs to $\mathbb R \setminus \text{Im}(h_\alpha)$?
About 2, given $x \in \mathbb R$, let's say that $F(\delta) = x$, where $\delta \in \omega_{\varepsilon}$, doesn't just follow by my definitions that:
$$f(x) = f(F(\delta)) = g_{\delta + 1}(F(\delta)) + h_{\delta + 1}(F(\delta)) = g(F(\delta)) + h(F(\delta)) = g(x) + h(x)$$
or am I wrong?
Edit 1. I fixed the little mess in the definitions of $g_{\alpha + 1}$ and $h_{\alpha + 1}$ (thx to @IzaakvanDongen for the remark).
Edit 2. As pointed out in the comments the statement of the problem is false for $g,h$ bijective and works only for $g,h$ injective.

I think what you have basically works. At stage $\alpha < \mathfrak c$ there are $\mathfrak c$-many pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a+b=f(F(\alpha))$ but we're only forbidden from using the $|\alpha|$-many pairs $(a,b)\in \operatorname{Im}(g_\alpha)\times \operatorname{Im}(h_\alpha),$ so we don't get stuck.

@lonzaleggiera, notice that the post starts by taking a well-ordering of $\Bbb R$. The minimum of this set is not with respect to the usual ordering but with respect to this well-ordering.

OP, good work so far! Is your task definitely "prove that every function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ can be written as a sum of two bijective functions"? I am afraid that I believe this statement is false. It's true if all you want is injective functions, and your proof more or less shows that, if you use spaceisdarkgreen's modification. (Maybe think about why you haven't shown surjectivity). Also I think technically your definition of $g_{\alpha + 1}$ doesn't make sense - did you really mean to take a union of a function and a real number?

@IzaakvanDongen why can't we have surjectivity as well?

@fantasie, https://mathoverflow.net/a/461598

@IzaakvanDongen Thank you for clearing that up. I've deleted my comment to reduce clutter, since  I believe your reply by  will be sufficient by itself to prevent anyone else from falling into the same misunderstanding.

@spaceisdarkgreen, I think you actually mean "we're forbidden from using the pairs $(a, b) \in (\mathrm{Im}(g_\alpha) \times \Bbb R) \cup (\Bbb R \times \mathrm{Im}(h_\alpha))$", right? There are still fewer than $\mathfrak c$ of these among pairs with $a + b = f(F(\alpha))$ of course, so the idea remains the same.

@IzaakvanDongen yep, definitely what I meant (and good catch on the surjective part).

@spaceisdarkgreen so you're just saying that at stage $\alpha < \omega_\varepsilon$, since, fixed $f(F(\alpha))$, there are $\mathfrak c$ $(a,b) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ such that $a + b = f(F(\alpha))$, and since the pairs we're forbidden from taking (the pairs $(a, b) \in (\mathrm{Im}(g_\alpha) \times \Bbb R) \cup (\Bbb R \times \mathrm{Im}(h_\alpha))$,  so that $a+b$), are $|\alpha|<\mathfrak c$, I can still choose a pair of value for $g_{\alpha+1}(F(\alpha))$ and $h_{\alpha+1}(F(\alpha))$ in a set whose cardinality is $\mathfrak c$ (and in particular it's non empty) 1/2

this assures me that in every passage of the construction the minimums exist, correct?
Moreover, for 2. I deduce from your first answer that what I wrote is sufficient/correct to guarantee that $f = h + g$, am I correct?  2/2

@leluch_l8r4 yes, although I made the oversight that Izaak corrected that this only produces injective functions (and bijective is impossible).

@IzaakvanDongen the problem comes from a past exam (for whom I don't have any solution) so It might be that my professor made a mistake. Thank you for letting me notice it and for the counterexample to surjectivity. Now I think my construction works for $g,h$ injective, since when I define them as a union of injective maps the injectivity is preserved, but I could not say anything about  surjectivity, and that's should be all

Summary of the discussion in the comments to the OP
As pointed out by @IzaakvanDongen the statement of the problem is false if it requires $g$ and $h$ bijective (see here for a counterexample to surjectivity), but it's true asking for $g$ and $h$ to be only injectives. And so the construction in the original post actually works to get $g$ and $h$ injective functions (the union respectively of $(g_\alpha)_{\alpha \in \omega_{\varepsilon}}$ and $(h_\alpha)_{\alpha \in \omega_{\varepsilon}}$ preservers the injectivity). 
The verification of the propriety in 2 is also correct as stated above. About 1, firstly we notice that given $f(F(\alpha)) \in \mathbb R$ there are $|\mathbb R|$ pairs $(a,b) \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ such that $a + b = f(F(\alpha))$, we'll denote the set of these pairs with $X_{f(F(\alpha))}$ ($|X_{f(F(\alpha))}| = |\mathbb R|$). At each $\alpha$ stage, with $\alpha \in \omega_\varepsilon$, we have to exclude from $X_{f(F(\alpha))}$ the pairs in $((\mathrm{Im}(g_\alpha) \times \Bbb R) \cup (\Bbb R \times \mathrm{Im}(h_\alpha))) \cap X_{f(F(\alpha))}$, and choose a couple of values for $g_{\alpha+1}(f(F(\alpha)))$ and $h_{\alpha+1}(f(F(\alpha)))$. Since:
$$|((\mathrm{Im}(g_\alpha) \times \Bbb R) \cup (\Bbb R \times \mathrm{Im}(h_\alpha))) \cap X_{f(F(\alpha))}| = |((\mathrm{Im}(g_\alpha) \times \Bbb R) \cap X_{f(F(\alpha))}) \cup ((\Bbb R \times \mathrm{Im}(h_\alpha))) \cap X_{f(F(\alpha))})| \leq |(\mathrm{Im}(g_\alpha) \times \Bbb R) \cap X_{f(F(\alpha))})| + |(\Bbb R \times \mathrm{Im}(h_\alpha))) \cap X_{f(F(\alpha))})| = |\alpha| + |\alpha| < |\mathbb R|$$
we get $|X_{f(F(\alpha))} \setminus ((\mathrm{Im}(g_\alpha) \times \Bbb R) \cup (\Bbb R \times \mathrm{Im}(h_\alpha)))| = |\mathbb R| \implies X_{f(F(\alpha))} \setminus ((\mathrm{Im}(g_\alpha) \times \Bbb R) \cup (\Bbb R \times \mathrm{Im}(h_\alpha))) \ne \emptyset$, so we can chose a pair of values for $g_{\alpha+1}(f(F(\alpha)))$ and $h_{\alpha+1}(f(F(\alpha)))$, and we're done.
(Thanks to @spaceisdarkgreen and @IzaakvanDongen for the helpful suggestions).
